# How to seek in videos stored on Azure Storage

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-storage

Is there a way you can seek in videos that are stored on Azure Storage? I found a few articles talking about Azure Media Services, but that's a bit overkill, because it's only a few videos. The problem is that the videos can be up to 30 minutes, so users should be able to skip the first 15 min if they want.

I now use VideoJS to show the videos on a website, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following:

- Make sure your blob is of Block Blob type
- Update the content type of your video to correspond to the format (i.e. video/mp4)
- use the Azure Media Player - https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/

Now you can seek through the video.